# How to check if a point is inside of a 3d shape

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates, minecraft

So this is a weird one.

I'm working on a game that is similar to Minecraft, but instead of cubes, it is done with Truncated Octahedrons *"See image below"*. To place or break a block, I need to get the coordinate where the player is looking and figure out which block it is within. I am not ray tracing, I am checking at intervals in front of the player until it intersects with something. I can check the position of when it intersects and the points before it intersects.

These things (Nickname: Mecon)

[image: Mecon]
The issue is, they are not rigid bodies. And the point can not access which mecon it is intersecting, just that it has intersected something. These shapes fill an area 100% with no holes, and can only be at coordinates of (even, even, even) or (odd, odd, odd)

(EX: [2, 2, 2] [3, 3, 3] [6, 14, 2] [13, 19, 7])

There will NEVER be a mecon at coordinate [2, 13, 6] or [23, 14, 8] since all values are not either all even or all odd

Here are all the coordinates to draw the mecon with verticies

```
    //Top Face
    new Vector3(0.25f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
    new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, -0.25f),
    new Vector3(-0.25f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
    new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, .25f),

    //Right Face
    new Vector3(0.0f, 0.75f, 0.5f),
    new Vector3(-0.25f, 0.5f, 0.5f),
    new Vector3(0.0f, 0.25f, 0.5f),
    new Vector3(0.25f, 0.5f, 0.5f),

    //Back Face
    new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.25f),
    new Vector3(0.5f, 0.75f, 0.0f),
    new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.25f),
    new Vector3(0.5f, 0.25f, 0.0f),

    //Bottom Face
    new Vector3(0.25f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.25f),
    new Vector3(-0.25f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -0.25f),

    //Left Face
    new Vector3(0.0f, 0.25f, -0.5f),
    new Vector3(0.25f, 0.5f, -0.5f),
    new Vector3(0.0f, 0.75f, -0.5f),
    new Vector3(-0.25f, 0.5f, -0.5f),

    //Front Face
    new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.25f),
    new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.75f, 0.0f),
    new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.25f),
    new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.25f, 0.0f)
```

Is there a way I can get any cartesian coordinate and get the coordinate of the mecon. So if I take the coordinates (11.878, 13.415, 4.383) it would return (12, 12, 4) The coordinate of the mecon is at the base of the mecon. (So the center of the mecon at (0, 0, 0) would be at (0, 1, 0) I just need the coordinate at the base)

If anything is confusing which I'm sure it all is, Ill try to answer any other questions you guys have.

Thank you!

UPDATE:
I now have it working on a singular mecon at .5 intervals of the Y (0, .5, 1, 1.5, and 2)

```
    if (this.transform.position.y == 0f)
        if (Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.x) + Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.z) <= .5f)
            Debug.Log("Inside");
        else
            Debug.Log("Outside");


    else if (this.transform.position.y == .5f)
        if (Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.x) + Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.z) <= 1f)
            Debug.Log("Inside");
        else
            Debug.Log("Outside");


    else if (this.transform.position.y == 1f)
        if ((Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.z) < 1f && Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.x) < .5f) || 
            (Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.x) < 1f && Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.z) < .5f) ||
            (Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.z) > .5f && Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.z) > .5f && Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.z) + Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.x) < 1.5f))
            Debug.Log("Inside");
        else
            Debug.Log("Outside");


    else if (this.transform.position.y == 1.5f)
        if (Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.x) + Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.z) <= 1f)
            Debug.Log("Inside");
        else
            Debug.Log("Outside");


    else if (this.transform.position.y == 2f)
        if (Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.x) + Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.z) <= .5f)
            Debug.Log("Inside");
        else
            Debug.Log("Outside");
```

Comment: So what you want is a function that wherever you look (input = random coordinates) gives you an output of the valid coordinates for your mecon (output = all odd or all even coordinates)??. It is not clear for me. Please clarify what you want concretely, with sample of what you tried so far and where are you stuck

Comment: How do you get the intersection point? Raycast or something else?

Comment: The way I will be doing it is by checking a point away from the camera, if there is no intersection, check another point a certain distance away, and repeat, until it intersects a mecon. At that point I need to be able to tell which mecon I have collided with. For now, that functionality is not in, since the entire game had to be reformatted from its previous version. Currently, I want to pass a random coordinate, and be returned the coordinate of the mecon it is inside of. I can then use that in my code when I use the camera to get which mecon I am looking at

Comment: @RustyBucketBay